# Why does my form validation using JavaScript not prevent the form from being sent?

Tags: php, javascript

i have this small javascript to check if the email is valid, i check client side, couse its not 100% important that the mail is valid, and i dont want to re-direct the user just to check.

The issue is that the popup does apear, but the users values are still inserted

```
  <script>
function popup()
{  

    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var atpos=email.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=email.lastIndexOf(".");

if (document.getElementById("email").value == "") {

    alert("Enter an email");
    return false;

 }
else if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length) {

    alert("The email is not valid");
    return false;

 }
else
    window.location = "email.php";
    return true;
}
   </script>
```

and here is the HTML form

```
 <form action="email.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="signup_form" id="signup_form" method="post">


<input class="txt accent-color colorize_border-color required" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Indtast E-mail her" data-label-text="Email" type="email">

<input class="submit button big btn" id="submit_button" name="submit" value="Deltag nu!" onclick="return popup()"  type="submit">

</form>
```

if i remove "type submit" it works, but i dont get the values with $_POST on the next page, they are null.

Any way to get around this?

Comment: Also use onsubmit of the form instead of onclick of the button. Use `onsubmit="return validate(this)"` and return false from the function to stop submission and try to allow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canonical

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById(("signup_form").onsubmit=function() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var atpos=email.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=email.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (document.getElementById("email").value == "") {
      alert("Enter an email");
      return false;
    }
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length) {
      alert("The email is not valid");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
 }
```

using

```
<form action="email.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="signup_form" id="signup_form" method="post">
  <input class="txt accent-color colorize_border-color required" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Indtast E-mail her" data-label-text="Email" type="email">
  <input class="submit button big btn" id="submit_button" name="submit" value="Deltag nu!"   type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Clarification for the OP: The validation function must be tied to the form's `onsubmit` event because it is this event that must receive `return false` to stop the form submission.